# Kafka Connect JSON format

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a topic titled `newtest` in Kafka with three messages:

```
Hello 
Is anybody out there
Can you hear me
```

...and I have the following config for a connect job:

```
{
    "name":"connect-test-9",
    "config":
    {
        "connector.class":"FileStreamSink",
        "file":"connector-test",
        "topics":"newtest",
        "name":"connect-test-9",
        "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
        "transforms":"Hoist, AddTimestamp",
        "transforms.Hoist.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField$Value",
        "transforms.Hoist.field":"line",
        "transforms.AddTimestamp.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
        "transforms.AddTimestamp.timestamp.field":"Timestamp"
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following output in file `connector-test`:

```
Struct{line=Hello,Timestamp=Mon Mar 12 14:50:34 PDT 2018}
Struct{line=Is anybody out there,Timestamp=Mon Mar 12 14:50:44 PDT 2018}
Struct{line=Can you hear me,Timestamp=Mon Mar 12 14:50:52 PDT 2018}
```

I would like to get this:

```
{"line":"Hello","Timestamp":"Mon Mar 12 14:50:34 PDT 2018"}
{"line":"Is anybody out there","Timestamp":"Mon Mar 12 14:50:44 PDT 2018"}
{"line":"Can you hear me","Timestamp":"Mon Mar 12 14:50:52 PDT 2018"}
```

I've tried changing the value.converter, no good (parse exception). I also have another topic where the message is already Json, and the parse succeeds there, and I can add a Timestamp without Hoist. But my output is the same non-Json format `{key1=value1,key2=value2}`.

Any way I can get the output in proper JSON?

---

This is the parse exception that I see:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Can': was expecting ('true', 'false', or 'null')`

Comment: Why are you using string converter if you want JSON? Can you add the parse exception to the question?

Comment: Edited question with parse exception. The source topic is a plain string. Doesn't the converter have to match what the source is?

Comment: Your source data isn't JSON. It's a String. You need to *send* JSON, if you want to *consume* JSON. The `Struct{line=message, Timestamp=...}` output is correct for the data you provided.

Comment: My source isn't a file. It's a topic. The topic has three string (non-JSON) messages. I would like to use Connect to convert them to JSON and add a timestamp. Is this possible?

Comment: Updated my answer, by the way

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solved it?

I produce plain text on topic A, consume by sink from A, then write messages in JSON format to file

Comment: This is a while back, but IIRC, the answer is no, or it was at the time.

Answer (score 3):

To get JSON output, you need to use the `JsonConverter` rather than the `StringConverter` [the converter happens before the sink, and after the consumer deserialization](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained)

Your data is already in Kafka, and you used a Source Connector, perhaps with a `StringConveter` to ingest, then you convert to the internal `Struct`, which can be setup with a Sink Connector and a different Converter type